# How to mount Cloud Filestore in GCP AI platform Jupyter notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab, gcp-ai-platform-notebook, google-cloud-filestore

I want to mount a Cloud Filestore instance in a GCP AI Platform Jupyter notebook instance so that I don't have to upload all of my data into the notebook.

I followed the instructions at https://cloud.google.com/filestore/docs/mounting-fileshares, but get these error messages:

```sh
root@0084329abd1b:/home# mount <IP_ADDRESS>:/streams cfs
mount.nfs: rpc.statd is not running but is required for remote locking.
mount.nfs: Either use '-o nolock' to keep locks local, or start statd.
root@0084329abd1b:/home# mount -o nolock <IP_ADDRESS>:/streams cfs
mount.nfs: Operation not permitted
```

Comment: to mount buckets, check out `gcsfuse`: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a Filestore instance [link](https://cloud.google.com/filestore/docs/creating-instances)
2. Crerate a Google VM instance [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-start-instance)
3. Create a Notebook AI instance [link](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/notebooks/docs/create-new)
4. On the VM instance run the commands:

   ```
   sudo apt-get -y update
   sudo apt-get -y install nfs-common
   sudo mkdir test
   # fileshare remote target
   sudo mount 111.11.111.11:/fileshare test
   sudo chmod go+rw test
   echo 'This is a test' > test/testfile
   ls test 
   #testfile
   ```
5. On the Notebook AI instance run the commands [link](https://cloud.google.com/filestore/docs/mounting-fileshares):

   ```
   sudo apt-get -y update
   sudo apt-get -y install nfs-common
   sudo mkdir test
   # fileshare remote target
   sudo mount 111.11.111.11:/fileshare /test
   ls test
   #testfile
   ```

You can also check [link](https://backdrift.org/fixing-rpc-statd-running-required-remote-locking)

Comment: Why are you creating a VM instance? The creation of the AI Notebook automatically creates the underlying instance.

Comment: just for testing purposes, to test if I can find the files from my VM on AI Notebook after mounting the folder. You can see that the file `testfile` on the VM can be reached from AI Notebook on this example.

Comment: Looks like my issue is in how I'm customizing my jupyter container. If I just use the out of the box tensorflow 2.0 instance, the mount works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From your terminal, you can do something like this.

```
mkdir des_bucket
gcsfuse --debug_gcs --implicit-dirs  src_bucket des_bucket
```